# Ok, can you spot a syntax error here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eclipse is givign me a syntax error along these lines but I don't see anything wrong there:

```
$('.addNewFolder').click(function() {
    showModal('modal_div', 'Nový adresár');
    var id = '<?php echo ToHtml($idFolder); ?>';
    $('.folders .trow1').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') == 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' || $(this).css('backgroundColor') == '#346cb6') {
            id = $(this).attr('rel');
        }
    });
    ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderAdd.php?idFolder='+id);
});
```

After PHP parsing:

```
$('.addNewFolder').click(function() {
    showModal('modal_div', 'Nový adresár');
    var id = '';
    $('.folders .trow1').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') == 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' || $(this).css('backgroundColor') == '#346cb6') {
            id = $(this).attr('rel');
        }
    });
    ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderAdd.php?idFolder='+id);
});
```

This is what IDE says:

```
Syntax error on token "}", invalid MethodHeaderName
```

I've been staring at that code for at least half an hour. I am either blind or going crazy.

EDIT:

The whole javascript on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

    function in_array (needle, haystack, argStrict) {
        var key = '', strict = !!argStrict; 
        if (strict) {
            for (key in haystack) {
                if (haystack[key] === needle) {
                    return true;            }
            }
        } else {
            for (key in haystack) {
                if (haystack[key] == needle) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
         return false;
    }

    var openedFolders = new Array();
    <?php if (count($_SESSION['ECM']['openedSlideFolders']) > 0) : ?>
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_SESSION['ECM']['openedSlideFolders'] as $aVal): ?>
        <?php echo "openedFolders[$i] = '$aVal';\n"; ?>
    <?php ++$i; endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    var start = 0;
    var stop = 0;
    $('.drag').each(function() {
        var draggables = $(this).parents('table').find('.drag');
        var $next = draggables.filter(':gt(' + draggables.index(this) + ')').first();
        var width = $(this).css('width');
        var nextWidth = $next.css('width');
        if (nextWidth > width && 30 == parseInt(width)) {
            $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
            $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
            if (in_array($(this).attr('rel'), openedFolders)) {
                $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
            }               
        }
        if (in_array($(this).attr('rel'), openedFolders)) {
            start = 1;
        }
        if (1 == start && stop < 2) {               
            if (30 == parseInt(width)) {
                stop++;
            }
        } else {
            start = 0;
            stop = 0;
            if (parseInt(width) > 30) {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            }
        }
    });

    function dragDrop()
    {
        $('.folders .trow1').hover(
            function () {
                if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' && $(this).css('backgroundColor') != '#346cb6') {
                    $(this).css('background', "#C2E3EF");
                }
            },
            function () {
                if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' && $(this).css('backgroundColor') != '#346cb6') {
                    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');   
                }
            }
        );

        $('.drag').click(function() {
            var draggables = $(this).parents('table').find('.drag');
            var $next = draggables.filter(':gt(' + draggables.index(this) + ')').first();
            var width = $(this).css('width');
            var nextWidth = $next.css('width');
            if (nextWidth > width && 30 == parseInt(width)) {
                var isVisible = $next.is(':visible');
                if (isVisible) {
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                    $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                    $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                }
                clickedId = $(this).attr('rel');
                $.ajax({
                    type:    'POST',
                    url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/setOpenedFolder.php',
                    data:    'id='+clickedId,
                    success: function(msg){
                        //alert(msg);
                    }
                });
                var start = 0;
                var stop = 0;
                var i = 0;
                $('.drag').each(function() {
                    if (0 == start) {
                        iteratedId = $(this).attr('rel');
                        if (iteratedId == clickedId) {
                            start = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (1 == start && stop < 2) {
                        if ($(this).css('width') > width) {
                            if (isVisible) {
                                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
                            } else {
                                $(this).parent().parent().show();
                            }                           
                        } else {
                            stop++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            }
        }); 

        var dragId = 0;
        var dropId = 0;
        var isFile = false;

        $('.drag').mousedown(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                dragId = $(this).attr('rel');
                dragId = dragId.split(',');
                dragId = dragId[0];
            }
            isFile = false;
        });

        $('.drag2').mousedown(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                dragId = $(this).attr('rel');
                dragId = dragId.split(',');
                dragId = dragId[0];
            }
            isFile = true;
        }); 

        $('.drag').draggable({ 
            revert: true,
            cursorAt: {top: 0, left: 0}
        });

        $('.drag2').draggable({
            revert: true,
            cursorAt: {top: 0, left: 0}
        });


        $('.drop').droppable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            drop: function() {
                if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                    dropId = $(this).attr('rel');
                    dropId = dropId.split(',');
                    dropId = dropId[0];
                    if (dropId != dragId) {
                        if (false == isFile) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type:    'POST',
                                url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/folderMove.php',
                                data:    'nid='+dragId+'&pid='+dropId,
                                success: function(msg){
                                    <?php echo $aJsOnDrop; ?>;
                                    dragDrop();
                                }
                            });
                        } else if (true == isFile) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type:    'POST',
                                url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/slideMove.php',
                                data:    'fid='+dragId+'&did='+dropId,
                                success: function(msg){
                                    <?php echo $aJsOnDrop; ?>;
                                    dragDrop();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
        });

    }

    dragDrop();

    $('.folderListOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel')+'&browse=<?php echo $browse; ?>';
        ajaxElementCall('obrazy_list', '<?php echo $dirPrefixBody; ?>/listBase.php?'+append);
        dragDrop();
        $('.trow1').css('background', 'transparent');
        $('.trow1').css('color', '#3e4245');
        $(this).parent().css('background', "#346cb6 url('img/menuButtonOver.png') left top repeat-x");
        $(this).parent().css('color', 'white');
    });

    $('.rootFolderListOnclick').click(function() {
        window.location = 'navigator.php?kam=obrazy';
        dragDrop();
    });

    $('.folderEditOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel');
        showModal('modal_div', 'Editácia adresára'); 
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', '<?php echo $dirPrefixBody; ?>/folderEdit.php?kam=edit1&'+append);
    });

    $('.folderDeleteOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel');
        showModal('modal_div', 'Vymazanie adresára'); 
        // TODO 0 Nemam sajnu, aka chyba je tuna - Eclipse mi tu hadze syntax error
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', '<?php echo $dirPrefixBody; ?>/folderDelete.php?kam=del1&'+append);
    });

    $('.addNewFolder').click(function() {
        showModal('modal_div', 'Nový adresár');
        var id = '<?php echo ToHtml($idFolder); ?>';
        $('.folders .trow1').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') == 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' || $(this).css('backgroundColor') == '#346cb6') {
                id = $(this).attr('rel');
            }
        });
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderAdd.php?idFolder='+id);
    });

});    //-->
</script>
```

After PHP parsing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

    function in_array (needle, haystack, argStrict) {
        var key = '', strict = !!argStrict; 
        if (strict) {
            for (key in haystack) {
                if (haystack[key] === needle) {
                    return true;            }
            }
        } else {
            for (key in haystack) {
                if (haystack[key] == needle) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
         return false;
    }

    var openedFolders = new Array();
                openedFolders[0] = '3';

    var start = 0;
    var stop = 0;
    $('.drag').each(function() {
        var draggables = $(this).parents('table').find('.drag');
        var $next = draggables.filter(':gt(' + draggables.index(this) + ')').first();
        var width = $(this).css('width');
        var nextWidth = $next.css('width');
        if (nextWidth > width && 30 == parseInt(width)) {
            $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
            $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
            if (in_array($(this).attr('rel'), openedFolders)) {
                $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
            }               
        }
        if (in_array($(this).attr('rel'), openedFolders)) {
            start = 1;
        }
        if (1 == start && stop < 2) {               
            if (30 == parseInt(width)) {
                stop++;
            }
        } else {
            start = 0;
            stop = 0;
            if (parseInt(width) > 30) {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            }
        }
    });

    function dragDrop()
    {
        $('.folders .trow1').hover(
            function () {
                if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' && $(this).css('backgroundColor') != '#346cb6') {
                    $(this).css('background', "#C2E3EF");
                }
            },
            function () {
                if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' && $(this).css('backgroundColor') != '#346cb6') {
                    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');   
                }
            }
        );

        $('.drag').click(function() {
            var draggables = $(this).parents('table').find('.drag');
            var $next = draggables.filter(':gt(' + draggables.index(this) + ')').first();
            var width = $(this).css('width');
            var nextWidth = $next.css('width');
            if (nextWidth > width && 30 == parseInt(width)) {
                var isVisible = $next.is(':visible');
                if (isVisible) {
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                    $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderClosed');
                    $(this).removeClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                    $(this).addClass('ordinaryFolderOpened');
                }
                clickedId = $(this).attr('rel');
                $.ajax({
                    type:    'POST',
                    url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/setOpenedFolder.php',
                    data:    'id='+clickedId,
                    success: function(msg){
                        //alert(msg);
                    }
                });
                var start = 0;
                var stop = 0;
                var i = 0;
                $('.drag').each(function() {
                    if (0 == start) {
                        iteratedId = $(this).attr('rel');
                        if (iteratedId == clickedId) {
                            start = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (1 == start && stop < 2) {
                        if ($(this).css('width') > width) {
                            if (isVisible) {
                                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
                            } else {
                                $(this).parent().parent().show();
                            }                           
                        } else {
                            stop++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            }
        }); 

        var dragId = 0;
        var dropId = 0;
        var isFile = false;

        $('.drag').mousedown(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                dragId = $(this).attr('rel');
                dragId = dragId.split(',');
                dragId = dragId[0];
            }
            isFile = false;
        });

        $('.drag2').mousedown(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                dragId = $(this).attr('rel');
                dragId = dragId.split(',');
                dragId = dragId[0];
            }
            isFile = true;
        }); 

        $('.drag').draggable({ 
            revert: true,
            cursorAt: {top: 0, left: 0}
        });

        $('.drag2').draggable({
            revert: true,
            cursorAt: {top: 0, left: 0}
        });


        $('.drop').droppable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            drop: function() {
                if ($(this).attr('rel') !== undefined) {
                    dropId = $(this).attr('rel');
                    dropId = dropId.split(',');
                    dropId = dropId[0];
                    if (dropId != dragId) {
                        if (false == isFile) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type:    'POST',
                                url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/folderMove.php',
                                data:    'nid='+dragId+'&pid='+dropId,
                                success: function(msg){
                                    ajaxElementCall('__folderList', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folders.php?browse=0&idFolder=', 'obrazy_list', 'body/obsah/obrazy/listBase.php?browse=0&idFolder=');
                                    dragDrop();
                                }
                            });
                        } else if (true == isFile) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type:    'POST',
                                url:     'body/obsah/obrazy/slideMove.php',
                                data:    'fid='+dragId+'&did='+dropId,
                                success: function(msg){
                                    ajaxElementCall('__folderList', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folders.php?browse=0&idFolder=', 'obrazy_list', 'body/obsah/obrazy/listBase.php?browse=0&idFolder=');
                                    dragDrop();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
        });

    }

    dragDrop();

    $('.folderListOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel')+'&browse=0';
        ajaxElementCall('obrazy_list', 'body/obsah/obrazy/listBase.php?'+append);
        dragDrop();
        $('.trow1').css('background', 'transparent');
        $('.trow1').css('color', '#3e4245');
        $(this).parent().css('background', "#346cb6 url('img/menuButtonOver.png') left top repeat-x");
        $(this).parent().css('color', 'white');
    });

    $('.rootFolderListOnclick').click(function() {
        window.location = 'navigator.php?kam=obrazy';
        dragDrop();
    });

    $('.folderEditOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel');
        showModal('modal_div', 'Editácia adresára'); 
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderEdit.php?kam=edit1&'+append);
    });

    $('.folderDeleteOnclick').click(function() {
        var append = 'idFolder='+$(this).attr('rel');
        showModal('modal_div', 'Vymazanie adresára'); 
        // TODO 0 Nemam sajnu, aka chyba je tuna - Eclipse mi tu hadze syntax error
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderDelete.php?kam=del1&'+append);
    });

    $('.addNewFolder').click(function() {
        showModal('modal_div', 'Nový adresár');
        var id = '';
        $('.folders .trow1').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('backgroundColor') == 'rgb(52, 108, 182)' || $(this).css('backgroundColor') == '#346cb6') {
                id = $(this).attr('rel');
            }
        });
        ajaxElementCall('modal_div', 'body/obsah/obrazy/folderAdd.php?idFolder='+id);
    });

});    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: I tend to agree; nothing wrong with that, is Eclipse preventing it from running? Is it complaining about something else? I don't use Eclipse personally but I know it does sometimes get this stuff wrong ...

Comment: You're neither blind nor crazy, unless you're looking at the wrong code segment for the error. There's no syntax error in that code, so either the error's for a different bit of code, or Eclipse is wrong. Either is possible, I'd say :) It's not easy detecting syntax errors perfectly in mixed Javascript and PHP.

Comment: could it be complaining about the result from the call

Comment: Staring usually doesn't help when coding.  Debugging usually includes *doing* stuff.  The code you posted has no syntax errors itself, but there may be a problem with Eclipse parsing the string `'Nový adresár'`.  Have you tried replacing it with something else?

Comment: Well, even I dont see anything related with '}', are you sure this is place where the error lies. Completely remove this code, see if the error still follows.

Comment: @Greg at id = $(this).attr('rel'); line.

Comment: I have added the whle javascript code just in case error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Richard: Could you post what that JS looks like on the page (i.e. after the PHP has run)?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error (with the error message tooltip visible)?

Comment: @Tim Down I have posted js code after PHP parsing.

Comment: Having looked at the whole code (and pasted it, minus the PHP content, into [The Online Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)), I'd still say that there's no syntax error in the Javascript, and that if that if Eclipse is telling you that there is, then Eclipse is wrong. Sometimes tools aren't perfect. Does the code _run_, in different browsers? Chances are relatively good that if it does, then there's not actually a syntax error there.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Well, that's not good. It's not the first time. Eclipse often tries to persuade me there are errors in my javascript and I then spend hours staring at my code without errors like a fool. It's really driving me nuts.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Post it as an answer (that there is no error, it's just Eclipse is not good at checking js) and I will accept it. The code seems to work alright, I cannot find any errors with firebug or firefox error console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the whole code (and pasted it, minus the PHP content, into [The Online Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)), I'd still say that there's no syntax error in the Javascript, and that if that if Eclipse is telling you that there is, then Eclipse is wrong. Sometimes tools aren't perfect.

Does the code run, in different browsers? Chances are relatively good that if it does, then there's not actually a syntax error there.

(Posted as answer as requested. Ta.)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the accented characters in your quotes, you can still output accents, but use the corresponding HTML code.

A list of accented characters' HTML codes are found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: Better yet, use Unicode escapes, as there's no indication the string is being used as HTML.

Comment: How would using HTML entities help in JavaScript?

Comment: @Tim Down, Replacing the characters with Unicode escapes (or HTML entities) simplifies the character set of the JavaScript document.

Comment: @strager: I understand the Unicode escapes idea and have suggested it myself, but HTML entities within a JavaScript string literal will not help.

Comment: @Tim Down, I don't see why not.  `\u00FD` and `&#xFD;` are pretty similar as far as a dumb JS parser/highlighter is concerned.

Comment: @strager: An HTML entity in a JavaScript string literal will not be converted to a character. Try this HTML document: `<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><script>alert("&#xFD;")</script></head></html>`

Comment: @Tim Down, You are correct.  And if `$('body').html('&#xFD;')` is called, the appropriate character is inserted into the document.  I thought this is what @Greg was talking about.  I wasn't talking about the script being within HTML.

Comment: I never had a problem with using diactritique in JavaScript. As long as all files are saved as UTF-8, there never really has been a problem.